# Draw in a box in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a single page app and I want to include a signature box so my customer can sign on my iPad.

I have googled the life out of it and can't figure it out.  I'm new to Swift and don't 100% understand it.  I have some code that I have used from a YouTube channel, but this uses the whole screen.

```
import UIKit

class Canvas: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        //custom drawing
        super.draw(rect)

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {     return }

        //her are my lines
        // dummy data
        //        let startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        //        let endPoint = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        //
        //        context.move(to: startPoint)
        //        context.addLine(to: endPoint)

        context.setLineCap(.round)

        lines.forEach { (line) in
            for (i, p) in line.enumerated() {
                if i == 0 {
                    context.move(to: p)
                } else {
                    context.addLine(to: p)
                }
            }
        }

        context.strokePath()
    }

    //var line = [CGPoint]()

    var lines = [[CGPoint]]()

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event:     UIEvent?) {
        lines.append([CGPoint]())
    }

    //track finger as we move accross the screen
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event:      UIEvent?) {
        guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: nil) else {return}
        //print(point)

        guard var lastLine = lines.popLast() else {return}
        lastLine.append(point)
        lines.append(lastLine)

        //var lastLine = lines.last
        //lastLine?.append(point)

        //line.append(point)

        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let canvas = Canvas()

    override func loadView() {
        self.view = canvas
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        canvas.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```

Here is my latest code:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Draw
//
//  Created by Terry Cooke on 25/05/2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 Terry Cooke. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class Canvas: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var canvas: Canvas!

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        //custom drawing
        super.draw(rect)

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {return}

        context.setLineCap(.round)

        lines.forEach { (line) in
            for (i, p) in line.enumerated() {
                if i == 0 {
                    context.move(to: p)
                } else {
                    context.addLine(to: p)
                }
            }
        }

        context.strokePath()
    }

    var lines = [[CGPoint]]()

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event:     UIEvent?) {
        lines.append([CGPoint]())
    }

    //track finger as we move accross the screen
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event:      UIEvent?) {
        guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: nil) else {return}
        //print(point)

        guard var lastLine = lines.popLast() else {return}
        lastLine.append(point)
        lines.append(lastLine)

        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //let canvas = Canvas()

    //override func loadView() {
        //self.view = canvas
    //}

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .blue

        //view.addSubview(canvas)

        //canvas.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        //NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
//            canvas.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 600),
//            canvas.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250),
//            canvas.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
//            canvas.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
//            ])
//
        //canvas.backgroundColor = .white
    }

        //canvas.backgroundColor = .white
}
```

This allows you to draw in the whole screen, but I would line to contain this in a view box or image.

Comment: Where do you want to put the signiture view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just a signature box, make your `Canvas` a subview of `view`:

Get rid of `loadView()` and do:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .blue

    view.addSubview(canvas)

    canvas.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        canvas.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 600),
        canvas.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250),
        canvas.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        canvas.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
    ])

    canvas.backgroundColor = .white
}
```

You also need to fix the touches point to get it in the view itself:

Change:

```
guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: nil) else {return}
```

to:

```
guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self) else {return}
```

---

**Laying out the Canvas using the Storyboard:**

Instead of laying out the `Canvas` using code, you can add the `Canvas` view in the Storyboard directly:

1. Get rid of `let canvas = Canvas()` and the code that adds it as a view or subview.
2. In *Interface Builder*, drag out a `UIView` and place it over top of your `UIImageView` where you want it.  Add constraints from the edges of the `Canvas` to the edges of the `UIImageView`.
3. Click on the `Canvas` view and change its class to `Canvas` in the *Identity Inspector*.
4. Control drag from the `Canvas` view to your code and add the `@IBOutlet` called `canvas`:

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var canvas: Canvas!
   ```

---

**Clearing the Canvas**

Add this function to your `Canvas` class:

```
func clearCanvas() {
    lines = []
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Add a `Clear` button to your `ViewController` and use your `canvas` outlet to call `canvas.clearCanvas()` to erase the `Canvas`:

```
@IBAction func clear(_ sender: UIButton) {
    canvas.clearCanvas()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `Canvas` class to replace the `view` in your `ViewController`. Instead, you could try this:

```
override func loadView() {
    view.addSubview(canvas)
    canvas.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // Whatever constraints you want
    canvas.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
    canvas.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -100).isActive = true
    canvas.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
    canvas.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -100).isActive = true
}
```

This code adds the `canvas` as a view instead of replacing the view (which covers the whole screen).

Comment: Thanks George, With this code I'm getting Use of unresolved identifier 'addSubview'.  any ideas?